# How to offline the SSM FRAMEWORK?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I'm studying SSM (SPRING+SPRINGMVC+MYBATIS) framework for the development, but the working environment can not be directly connected to the Internet.

The current SSM framework is based on the MAVEN management, and needs to connect to the resource pool, even in the local establishment of resource pool and there are a lot of problems.

Who has experience in this regard, hope to give guidance!

Comment: Guidance about what?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a Maven "local repo" by downloading and installing the relevant artifacts, and then use it in offline mode.  You don't need to be connected to the internet to build.